# Using MySQL DAYNAME as Column Heading even with NULL result

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have a query doing most of what I need, but can't suss presentation logic for empty results.

Consider this query:

```
SELECT 
SUM(order_detail.price/order_detail.qty*order_detail.qty_dispatched) AS orderedPrice, 
orders.location, 
orders.id,
suppliers.supplier_name,
DAYNAME(FROM_UNIXTIME(orders.datetime)) AS Day_Name,
from_unixtime(orders.datetime) AS Day_Date
FROM orders, order_detail, products,suppliers 
WHERE (orders.datetime BETWEEN '$from_date' AND '$to_date'  
AND order_detail.order_id = orders.id  
AND orders.location LIKE '%$locations%'
AND  order_detail.product_id=products.id 
AND products.supplier_id IN ($suppliers)
AND suppliers.id IN ($suppliers)
AND products.supplier_id=suppliers.id
AND (orders.status <> 'deleted') )
```

If I get a result for **every** day of the week I can post process it with PHP and present the results as such:

```
Location | Supplier Name | Mon | Tue | Wed | Thu | Fri | Sat | Sun | Total
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
Alhambra | Widget Co     | $50 | $50 | $50 | $50 | $50 | $50 | $50 | $350
```

However, if there is no order on any day I obviously get no result and I can't hit upon a way to post process to  present $0 in a column.

I thought perhaps a **weekdays** table might be the answer with a JOIN but I can't figure it. Something like this?

```
CREATE TABLE week_days(
  week_day_num INT(11) DEFAULT NULL
);

INSERT INTO week_days(week_day_num) VALUES (1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7);

SELECT
DAYNAME(FROM_UNIXTIME(orders.datetime)) AS day_name,
SUM(order_detail.price/order_detail.qty*order_detail.qty_dispatched) AS orderedPrice,
COALESCE(SUM(order_detail.price/order_detail.qty*order_detail.qty_dispatched) AS orderedPrice , 0)
FROM week_days wd
LEFT JOIN (

SELECT 
orders.location, 
orders.id,
suppliers.supplier_name,
from_unixtime(orders.datetime) AS Day_Date
FROM orders, order_detail, products,suppliers 
WHERE (orders.datetime BETWEEN '$from_date' AND '$to_date'  
AND order_detail.order_id = orders.id  
AND orders.location LIKE '%$locations%'
AND  order_detail.product_id=products.id 
AND products.supplier_id IN ($suppliers)
AND suppliers.id IN ($suppliers)
AND products.supplier_id=suppliers.id
AND (orders.status <> 'deleted') )


) order_results
ON wd.week_day_num = DAYOFWEEK(FROM_UNIXTIME(orders.datetime))
GROUP BY
      products.supplier_id,orders.location,DAYOFWEEK(FROM_UNIXTIME(orders.datetime))

ORDER BY location, products.supplier_id,Day_Date ASC;
```

Comment: If you're pivoting it with PHP, why do you need a result for each day? The PHP can simply do `if (isset($data[$weekday])) { display results for that day; } else { display $0 }`.

Comment: I think GROUP BY should go inside your LEFT JOIN    and remove "products." in your ORDER BY.

Comment: @Barmar Each row is a single day, I need to amalgamate a week's worth for each location/supplier that has at least 1 result in a given week.

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax here is wroing:

```
COALESCE(SUM(order_detail.price/order_detail.qty*order_detail.qty_dispatched) AS orderedPrice , 0)
```

The `AS` clause needs to go outside the `COALESCE` function.

```
COALESCE(SUM(order_detail.price/order_detail.qty*order_detail.qty_dispatched), 0) AS orderedPrice
```

Comment: Thanks. I got the queries running but result set is off.

Comment: Still don't get the empty, days of the week also get an initial null row

Comment: Can you make a sqlfiddle with sample data?

Comment: I'll see if I can get something together. Ta.